# scrollViewWillEndDragging Snap to View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've looked all over the place, but can't get an answer. So, here goes. I created a long scroll view with 568 px (full screen) views inside. As the user scrolls down, I want the scroll view to snap to certain positions. Here's my code:

```
    -(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 468 && aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 668) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 568;
    } else if (aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 1036 && aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 1236) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 1136;
    } else if (aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 1604 && aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 1804) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 1704;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it snaps without inertia (when I lift up my finger), but when I swipe to scroll, it doesn't snap. I'm guessing that I could use velocity to deal with this but I don't know how. Any help with getting it to snap on swipe would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because swiping a UIScrollView only calls the `...Decelerating` methods. see the documentation of [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating%3a)

Comment: Okay, so what should I do?

Comment: I would suggest using `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`

Comment: Tried it, still didn't work. See edit. What should I do?

Comment: have you ever looked into the documentation? The method definition is `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` there's nothing like velocity etc.

Comment: I know, but without it, I can't set an offset. This doesn't work: `self.aboutScroller.contentOffset.y = 568;`

Comment: Never mind, got it to work with `[_aboutScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 568) animated:YES];` Thanks for the simple solution Daniel!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who needs to solve this problem, Daniel has it correct above, but I just wanted to put my own word in.

First, you add the method that sets the contentOffset if the user doesn't scroll with inertia:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
  if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 468 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 668) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 568;
    } else if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 1036 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 1236) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 1136;
    } else if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 1604 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 1804) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 1704;
    } else if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 2172 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 2372) {
        targetContentOffset->y = 2272;
    }
}
```

Next, you add the method that sets the contentOffset if the user does scroll with inertia:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 468 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 668) {
        [_aboutScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 568) animated:YES];
    } else if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 1036 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 1236) {
        [_aboutScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 1136) animated:YES];
    } else if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 1604 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 1804) {
        [_aboutScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 1704) animated:YES];
    } else if (_aboutScroller.contentOffset.y >= 2172 && _aboutScroller.contentOffset.y <= 2372) {
        [_aboutScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 2272) animated:YES];
    }
}
```